# Plotly: How to make different plots using plotly as a plotting backend for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Setting [plotly as a backend for pandas](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/), you can produce plots quickly and easily using:

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

How can you make this setup produce other plots than lineplots? And what other options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define which plot type you'd like to produce through the `kind` argument in:

```
df.plot(kind='line')
```

`kind='line'` produces the very same plot as in the question. Valid options are:

```
['scatter', 'line', 'area', 'bar',
 'barh', 'hist', 'box', 'violin',
 'strip', 'funnel', 'density_heatmap',
 'density_contour', 'imshow']
```

You can easily study them all by running:

```
for k in kinds[:-1]:
    df.plot(kind=k).show()
```

#### Plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that I've used `kinds[:-1]`. This is because `imshow` is for image data and requires a dataset a *bit* more complicated than `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Please refer to [this](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/) and [Plotting an image with imshow from a pandas dataframe](http://Plotting%20an%20image%20with%20imshow%20from%20a%20pandas%20dataframe)

In order to set the titles and title colors for all other options, here's a complete code snippet:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

kinds = ['scatter', 'line', 'area', 'bar', 'barh', 'hist', 'box', 'violin', 'strip', 'funnel', 'density_heatmap', 'density_contour', 'imshow']

for k in kinds[:-1]:
    fig = df.plot(kind=k, title = k)
    fig.update_layout(title = dict(font=dict(color='#EF553B')))
    fig.show()
```