# Column Sum bar chart in Plotly

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Chinese'] = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
df['Italian'] = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0]

df[['Italian','Chinese']].sum().plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

which gives me a plot using Matplotlib, how I can get the same plot using Plotly. Nowhere I was able to find the aggregation plot in plotly.

[image]

The reason I need it plotly is I need to integrate it with Dash App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set plotly as a [plotting backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664935/plotly-how-to-make-different-plots-using-plotly-as-a-plotting-backend-for-panda) for pandas with:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

And then use:

```
df[['Italian','Chinese']].sum().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Chinese'] = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
df['Italian'] = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
df[['Italian','Chinese']].sum().plot(kind = 'bar')
```